# I haved installed cocoapods. But I cannot use "pod search"

Tags: cocoapods

I haved installed cocoapods On EI. But I  cannot use "pod search"

```
DolphindeMacBook-Pro:~ dolphin$ pod --version
1.0.0
DolphindeMacBook-Pro:~ dolphin$ pod search afnetworking
Creating search index for spec repo 'master'.. Done![!] Unable to find a pod with name, author, summary, or descriptionmatching `afnetworking`
```

how to fix it

Comment: Why do you want to search for AFNetworking? You can install it by adding the following line to your podfile:

pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'

Comment: I wan to use pod in my project. The AFNworing is just a example.

Comment: Same problem here. Fresh, state-of-the-art install of everything (xcode, cocoapods, git…). `pod list | grep -i whatever` succeeds, but `pod search whatever` always fails, no matter what. I've cloned my `~/.cocoapods` from a working machine just in case, still fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be is creating search index, I also is same, you can wait patiently, as follows:

`$ pod search AFNetworking`

`Creating search index for spec repo 'master'.. Done!
Creating search index for spec repo 'master-1'.. Done!`

-> AFNetworking (3.1.0)
    A delightful iOS and OS X networking framework.
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.1.0'
   - Homepage: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking
   - Source:   https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git
   - Versions: 3.1.0, 3.0.4, 3.0.3, 3.0.2, 3.0.1, 3.0.0, 3.0.0-beta.3,
   3.0.0-beta.2, 3.0.0-beta.1, 2.6.3, 2.6.2, 2.6.1, 2.6.0, 2.5.4, 2.5.3, 2.5.2,
   2.5.1, 2.5.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.0, 2.2.4, 2.2.3, 2.2.2, 2.2.1, 2.2.0,
   2.1.0, 2.0.3, 2.0.2, 2.0.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.0-RC3, 2.0.0-RC2, 2.0.0-RC1, 1.3.4,
   1.3.3, 1.3.2, 1.3.1, 1.3.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.0, 1.1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0, 1.0RC3, 1.0RC2,
   1.0RC1, 0.10.1, 0.10.0, 0.9.2, 0.9.1, 0.9.0, 0.7.0, 0.5.1 [master repo]
   - Subspecs:
     - AFNetworking/Serialization (3.1.0)
     - AFNetworking/Security (3.1.0)
     - AFNetworking/Reachability (3.1.0)
     - AFNetworking/NSURLSession (3.1.0)
     - AFNetworking/UIKit (3.1.0)

`$ pod --version
1.0.1`

Answer (score 1):

- Open terminal and run `rm ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/search_index.json`
- pod search AFNetworking

---

Use `sudo rm ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/search_index.json` in case above command ask for permission

Answer (score 0):

With cocoapods installed, take the following steps:

- Open a terminal window, and $ cd into your project directory (cd ~/Path/To/Folder/Containing/your/app)
- Create a Podfile by running $ pod init
- Open the podfile (open -a Xcode Podfile) and add the podline and save the file, for example:

> pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'

- Run $ pod install in your project directory
- Open App.xcworkspace

Please find a more extended guide [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Analyzing dependencies
      [!] Unable to find a specification for `AFNetworking (~> 3.0)`

Comment: Can you post your full podfile and your terminal log

Comment: Alternatively, try this:

1) rm -rf ~/.cocoapods
2) pod setup
3) pod install